# How to remove the line that appears under each card in card view?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-cardview

I have a problem with the line that appears under each card as shown in this picture. Is there any way to remove it, or is it not possible?

Also, how can I present each card with a different color for example (purple and yellow)?

[image: this the line that I want to remove it]

This is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".benReqView">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button15"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/chat2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.6"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.977" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/benReqback"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"

        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/leftarrow"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/signupDon"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.021"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.073" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/benReqEmpty"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="23dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.086" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/benReqListView"
        android:layout_width="401dp"
        android:layout_height="539dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:background="#fafafa"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">


    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView23"
        android:layout_width="136dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/tajawalmedium2"
        android:text="حالة الطلبات"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.022" />

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView8"
    android:layout_width="414dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/footer" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/benReqToprofile"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/userr"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.82"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.977" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/benReqToHomeicon"
        android:layout_width="37dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:background="@drawable/home"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.17"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.988" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/benReq"
        android:layout_width="39dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/request"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.38"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.981" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: try setting `backgroundtint` as transparent in `ListView`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the line you're talking about is the `ListView`'s background appearing between your cards.
Try removing this line: `android:background="#fafafa"`

By the way, I suggest you to use a `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView`

Comment: I delete this line but nothing was changed

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `ListView`'s dividers by setting the divider's height to 0dp. Add the following lines to your `ListView`:

```
android:dividerHeight="0dp"
android:divider="@null"
```